# Display Javascript/Html/PHP as text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to display code on a webpage, just as text, for the user to view. The code snippet is obtained from a database, input using a form, and put in a div using PHP. Jquery is then used to replicate the html of that div in another element. The code from the database will never be executed; I am basically just making notes.

Code example: `alert('Hello')`; (could be PHP or html)

What is the best way of displaying this as text, in my browser?

1. Filter it somehow using PHP as it is input using a form.
2. Use of HTML tags (pre, xmp tags, CDDATA).
3. Convert special characters with some javascript function.
4. combination of the above.

Example of use below.

PHP

```
$inputQuery="SELECT x FROM y";  
$input = mysqli_query($dbc,$inputQuery);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($input);
//no issues above, just used to clarify the issue. If $input is javascript code, the  below doesn't work.

echo'
<div id="inputCode">'.$row["x"].'</div>';
```

JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY

```
var inputCode = $("#inputCode").html();
$( "#displayInputCode").html(inputCode);
```

Comment: no difference between inputCode and displayInputCode. I need it in two places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `htmlentities()` to convert all the HTML special characters to entities, so they won't be executed:

```
echo'
<div id="inputCode">'.htmlentities($row["x"]).'</div>';
```

Comment: Thanks. HTML entities takes care of things for the most part. One of this issues is when i have single quotes in the code i want to display. alert('hello'); does not work and messes up my PHP. alert("hello"); does work. Any ideas for that?

Comment: How does it mess up your PHP? It's in a variable, the quotes don't get interpreted.

Comment: The PHP error is:
mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given.

The first line of code in my initial question was simplified. It includes a WHERE clause and use of another PHP variable. The error points to row:  

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($input);  

Still, if the quotes are not interpreted in variables confusing as to why alert(''); doesnt work but alert(""); does.

Thanks again.

Comment: May have to re-draft this question if the above is getting messy!

Comment: Sounds like you're not using a parametrized query, and you're also not escaping the variable when you substitute it into the query. Isn't one of the points of using mysqli instead of mysql that you can use parametrized queries?

Comment: Probably :) its all a little new to me. What do you mean by escaping a variable? Below is the actual query. I will do some reading on parametrized queries.

Comment: $matchingAQuery="SELECT answer FROM question WHERE question='".$qRow['question']."'";

Comment: `$question = $dbc->real_escape_string($qRow['question']);`. But parametrized queries are better.

Comment: ah ok. real escape string fixes the error but displays text with \. eg. alert(\'Hello\'); Youve answered this question very well so i will have a go from here! much appreciated.

Comment: It shouldn't display like that. The backslashes don't get stored in the database, they're just used to make the query syntax correct. You must be doing some extra escaping when you retrieve and display.

Comment: yes sorry, i have some php which validates form input and puts it through mysqli_real_escape_string() before committing to database. I just doubled it up by using $question = $dbc->real_escape_string($qRow['question']); after pulling it out.

Comment: That's the right thing. Just make sure you only escape the input once, and don't escape it again when you retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

For HTML you can use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) which would protect against malicious data like `<script>` tags that include bad stuff; and for PHP you're already fine since `echo`'ing PHP code does not execute it (and browsers doesn't execute PHP code either).

Example code :

```
echo '<div id="inputCode">'.htmlentities($row["x"]).'</div>';
```

Comment: Thanks. HTML entities takes care of things for the most part. One of this issues is when i have single quotes in the code i want to display. alert('hello'); does not work and messes up my PHP. alert("hello"); does work. Any ideas for that?